Theorem environment and italics
In the following code, all theorems, remarks, and similar environments are displayed in italics. How should the settings be adjusted to improve this and display all of these in regular (upright) font?
I changed \theoremstyle{definition} or \theoremstyle{remark},but  all are displayed in italics again.
 \documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart}
    \usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{url,xspace, smfthm}
    %\usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % 余白を調整
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
    diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
    }
    \DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}
    \newtheoremstyle{uprightstyle}% Name
    {3pt}% Space above
    {3pt}% Space below
    {\normalfont}% Body font
    {}% Indent amount
    {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
    {.}% Punctuation after theorem head
    {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}% Space after theorem head
    {}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning normal)
    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
    \newtheorem{lem}[definition]{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{cor}[definition]{Corollary}
    \newtheorem{remark}[definition]{Remark}
    \usetikzlibrary{cd,bbox,babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
    %%%Below here are the main information about your paper: DO NOT MODIFY THEIR ORDER.
    \title{1+1=2}
    \date {July 25 2024}
    \author[A]{A}
    \email{ot.com}
    \keywords{1}
    % Fancyhdrパッケージを使ったヘッダーのカスタマイズ
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont Behavior of Tate-Shafarevich group of elliptic curves under quadratic field extension} % 左側に表示するヘッダーの内容とサイズ
    \fancyhead[R]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \thepage} % 右側にページ番号
    \begin{document}
    \begin{Theorem}
    $1+1=2$
    \end{Theorem}
    \end{document}


Why do you spend code for defining a theorem style that chooses upright font for the theorem body and then declare \theoremstyle{plain} that chooses italic type?

\theoremstyle{definition} or \theoremstyle{remark} will give upright body text.

@AndrewSwann When I changed that, all are displayed in italic again.

@egreg I changed \theoremstyle{definition}, but all are displayed in italic again .

@BrauerManinobstruction No. See my answer. Or you are doing something that your example code doesn't reveal.

@BrauerManinobstruction See edit to my answer.


I get ! LaTeX Error: Environment Theorem undefined.

Why are you loading smfthm? Do you know what it does?

Why are you defining uprightstyle and not use it?


\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{url,xspace, smfthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,bbox,babel}
%\usepackage{tikz-cd} % cd already does it

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % 余白を調整
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
  diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}

\newtheoremstyle{uprightstyle}% Name
  {3pt}% Space above
  {3pt}% Space below
  {\normalfont}% Body font
  {}% Indent amount
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {.}% Punctuation after theorem head
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}% Space after theorem head
  {}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning normal)

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont Behavior of Tate-Shafarevich group of elliptic curves under quadratic field extension} % 左側に表示するヘッダーの内容とサイズ
\fancyhead[R]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \thepage} % 右側にページ番号

\theoremstyle{uprightstyle}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{Theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[definition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[definition]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}[definition]{Remark}


\title{1+1=2}
\date {July 25 2024}
\author[A]{A}
\email{ot.com}
\keywords{1}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{Theorem}
This is a well-known fact, namely $1+1=2$.
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}

I removed sfmthm that does nothing that helps you. Also xspace is completely useless. Loading packages twice is likewise useless.

From your comments, with the help of my crystall ball, I deduced that you're actually using the environments provided by smfthm, such as
\begin{theo}
This is a well-known fact, namely $1+1=2$.
\end{theo}

which would print

Why? Because the Société mathématique de France wants theorems like this.
A declaration such as \theoremstyle{uprightstyle} takes effect only on theorem-like environments defined after the declaration has been issued. The environments provided by smfthm have already been defined.

Thank you very much. But when I deleted smfthm, I couldn't use \label and \ref and new 33 error occurred..

@BrauerManinobstruction Sorry, the crystal ball says nothing about this.

When I run your MWE error message displayed as Theorem was not defined, and the modified MWE is:
\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart}
    \usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{url,xspace, smfthm}
    %\usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % パッケージの追加
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % 余白を調整
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
    diagrams={>=Straight Barb}
    }
    \DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{OT2}{wncyr}{m}{n}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\Sha}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"58}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\Zhe}{\mathalpha}{cyrletters}{"11}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}

    \usetikzlibrary{cd,bbox,babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
    %%%Below here are the main information about your paper: DO NOT MODIFY THEIR ORDER.
    \title{1+1=2}
    \date {July 25 2024}
    \author[A]{A}
    \email{ot.com}
    \keywords{1}
    % Fancyhdrパッケージを使ったヘッダーのカスタマイズ
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont Behavior of Tate-Shafarevich group of elliptic curves under quadratic field extension} % 左側に表示するヘッダーの内容とサイズ
    \fancyhead[R]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \thepage} % 右側にページ番号
    \begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{uprightstyle}
    {6pt plus 5pt minus 2pt}% above space (default)
    {6pt plus 5pt minus 2pt}% below space
    {\upshape}% body
    {0em}% indent
    {\bfseries}% head
    {}% punct
    {.5em}% space
%    {}% custom
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }{#2}}%
 \thmnote{ {(#3)}}}% theorem head
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{uprightstyle}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

    \begin{Theorem}
This is for test    $1+1=2$
    \end{Theorem}
    \end{document}



Thank you very much. But when I deleted smfthm, I couldn't use \label and \ref and new 33 error occurred..
